# if statement does not work on javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

here is my trouble:

```
 $scope.Right = function () {
            if ($scope.SerialNumber < 5) { $scope.SerialNumber = $scope.SerialNumber + 1 } else { $scope.SerialNumber = $scope.SerialNumber };
            alert($scope.SerialNumber <5);
```

(I've been trying to use angularjs). so on alert it shows me 'false', but in real it does `$scope.SerialNumber + 1`

so basic if statement does not work (it works only if I use '===' statent, but I need here a '<'

Comment: `$scope.SerialNumber` starts out as `4` (making it `< 5`), then you increment it, and then it's no longer `<5`, so `alert` shows `false`. Why is this a problem?

Comment: the problem is that if I run with the code further, and I'll get to, say, '9', the SerialNumber in the if-statement will bacome '10', in spite it's clear 'false' on the if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just didn't write it out, but it appears you didn't close your function bracket.

Anyway, assuming you close your function brackets further down, what's probably happening is your `$scope.serialNumber` is 4, and then you add 1 to it, making it 5. Thus, in your first `if` statement, it's true, but then prints as false.

Comment: he problem is that if I run with the code further, and I'll get to, say, '9', the SerialNumber in the if-statement will bacome '10', in spite it's clear 'false' on the if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.Right = function () {
            if ($scope.SerialNumber + 1 < 5) { 
alert('False');
}
```

Not quite what you were looking for but it works assuming you want less than 5 to merely report false.

Comment: well, it's not so easy :( even when I get to '9' in my original code, I am returned 'false', but the SerialNumber gets the value '10'....

Comment: add $scope.SerialNumber - 1 before alert